# How to change a label on one UIView from another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Within my iPhone app I have 2 UIControls a ViewController.h and a selectionScreen.h.

The selectionScreen is set as so

```
@interface selectionScreen : ViewController{
```

I am trying to change a label that is placed in the main ViewController, from the selectionScreen

So far I have this within the SelectionScreen.m (personTotal1.text is the label in the other UIcontrol)

```
- (IBAction)Change:(id)sender{
    int x=123;
    NSString *y =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",x];
    personTotal1.text=y;
    NSLog(@"%@",personTotal1.text);
}
```

When I NSLog to check if the value has changed it returns null, how can I make it so interactions(such as a button press) within the Selectionscreen change label text in another screen.

Comment: Are these really different `UIViewControllers` or do you really mean they are different `UIControls`? Anyway, I would suggest declaring and then setting a weak reference to the UILabel you want to change on the object that you  are changing it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View controller:

Did you set your personTotal1 ivar as a property? Just setting the ivar is not enough:

```
UILabel *personTotal1;
```

You need to set the property and synthesize the getters and setters like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *personTotal1;
```

If you are using ARC then it would be like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *personTotal1;
```

Then be sure to synthesize the label. Now import the ViewController.h into the SelectionScreen file. From there you can access the UILabel properties. Hope this helps, if not let me know and I can clarify.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply,

I have set the property and synthesised within ViewController.m but I am still having problems. What else could be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hey mate, don't worry figured it out for myself. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: I have the same problem...  can you share your solution pls?